# How can I create a circle that contains two existing vertices?

Tags: modeling

[image: What I really want?]

Okay there are 2 verticies and one ellipse loop of edges. I want to make new loop containing these 2 verticies as shown. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficulty here lies in the fact that it no longer seems to be a circular path, it seems to be elliptical and slanted.

Anyway you could probably achieve this easily by basic *Extrude/Scale* workflow using your already drawn profile as snapping guide.

Just select your last edge loop, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, <kbd>Z</kbd> to restrict to the Z axis and then snap it to the first vertex of the guide.

To snap activate snapping to vertex in the 3d view header switch to *Vertex Snap* mode, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> during transform.

Afterwards press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to scale only in XY plane and then snap again to said vertex.

Repeat these steps until the complete shape is done.

[image: Extrude Snap Scale Snap]

In the end you may want to remove doubles to clean up the geometry by selecting all and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was a shortcut for this! ^^

Comment: You should explain how to enable snapping. And probably remove doubles at the end.

Comment: True, forgot about those, updated answer above. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Umm and what about non-symmetrical 2 vertices? Check out my image again. There are 2 non-symmetrical vertices. I currently do it by scaling/rotating/transforming. Kinda trial-and-error. @someonewithpc

Comment: You could use the *Grid Fill* operator for that, it must be a continuous loop and have the same amount of vertices in each opposing side. If you have any further doubts please post them as a new question, comments are not adequate place to provide full answers

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you will want to do is <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, enter *Edge Select Mode*, and select the edges.

[image]

Then key <kbd>P</kbd> and choose *By Selection*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*. Select the purely edges mesh. Go to the *Properties panel > Object Modifiers tab* and add a *Screw modifier*. Set the *Steps:* to 32. Disable *Smooth Shading*.

[image]

Apply it. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *Edit Mode*. Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected. Key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*. Go to *Toolshelf > Shading/UVs tab > Shading dropdown > Normals* and click *Recalculate*.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode*. Select the screwed mesh and then the cylinder. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected. Key <kbd>W</kbd> and select *Remove Doubles*.

Done.